# How to use an SQL cell as an array?

Tags: javascript, sql

Okay, so I'm making a dynamic website in javascript, and I have producers that I have added to an sql table. Each producer has their id, name and product which they are producing. The problem I am having is, I am unsure on how to add multiple products in the "product" column for each producer and how to get that information. This is my approach so far, but I am unsure if it's going to work out properly and I absolutely have no clue how to get that same information out.

```
    async add(name, product) {
    let sql = `SELECT * FROM producers WHERE name="${name}"`
    const data = await this.db.all(sql) //check what it returns

    //If it doesn't exist - add to database
    if(data.length === 0) {
        sql = `INSERT INTO producers (name, product) VALUES("${name}", "${product}")`
        await this.db.run(sql)
    //Else add product
    } else {
        const newproduct = (data[0].product) + (product)
        console.log(newproduct)
        sql = `UPDATE producers SET product=${newproduct} WHERE name="${name}"`
        console.log(product)
        await this.db.run(sql)
    }
}
```

So my question for this part is, would it make the product be for example if I have "shoes" already as the product and add "clothes", would the result be "shoesclothes" or would it be "shoes, clothes". And how do I get that same information out from the database, split into "shoes" and "clothes"?

This is how I've attempted to extract the data, but I have big doubts about this:

```
    async getProduct(product){
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM producers WHERE product="${product}"'
    const data = await this.db.all(sql)
    console.log(data)
    return data
}
```

Any help or pointers would be highly appreciated!

P.S. An alternative approach that I'm considering for this is adding a few more columns for "product 2" and "product 3" for example, but that would limit the amount of items that can be added to a producer and is not optimal.

P.P.S. Would it be maybe better if I use INSERT INTO rather than UPDATE?

The database is defined as follows:

```
    //Create Database Table if it doesn't exist
constructor(dbName = ':memory:') {
    return (async() => {
        this.db = await sqlite.open(dbName)
        const sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS producers(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE, name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, product TEXT NOT NULL)'
        await this.db.run(sql)
        return this
    })()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here lies with your design of the database itself, or possibly your understanding of basic SQL usage. For example, you have many producers. Each one has a name, but each can have many products. So what you should probably do is separate your products into another table.

As you have already noticed, you could start adding columns for product 1, product 2, product 3, etc. but you are putting limits on how many products a producer can have, and will have lots of empty values in your table.

---

## Relational Database Design

First, you will want a table just for the producers. This only contains information directly about a producer, not their products. When managing products via SQL you no longer need to worry about this table. You only update this table if information about the producers themselves changes, e.g. their name.

**TABLE `producers`**

```
id  |  name
--------------------
1   |  John
2   |  Bob
```

---

#### Linking Producers with Products

Now you'll want to create a table for your products.

**TABLE `products`**

```
id  |  name     |  producer_id
--------------------------------
1   |  Shoes    |  1
2   |  Shoes    |  2
3   |  Clothes  |  2
4   |  Belts    |  2
5   |  Hats     |  2
```

In this example, we can see that John and Bob both produce Shoes. Bob also produces Clothes, Belts and Hats. There's no limit to the number of products you can insert for each producer with this approach.

**SQL**

You can find all products for a producer by querying this table by `producer_id`. If you need to query by producer name, you need to use a [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) (I am unsure if you know how to use these).

```
SELECT products.name
FROM products
LEFT JOIN producers ON producers.id = products.producer_id
WHERE producers.name = 'Bob'
```

**Result**

This gives you four separate rows, which you can loop through in your JavaScript and work with properly.

```
Shoes
Cool
Belts
Hats
```

**Disclaimer**

As far as this design is concerned, John's shoe product and Bob's shoe product are considered two completely different things. In reality, maybe John and Bob are in fact just different producers of the exact same brand of shoe. If you need to update metadata about this same product for all producers (such as the product name), you need to update every row containing that same product. The example here is very simple, but this can turn into a significant problem with many related issues.

Ultimately, you probably want to make use of a third join table which sits between producers and products, used only to define the many to many relationship between them. I will not go into that here.

---

You may wish to read up on [relational database design](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html) to understand how you can use multiple database tables to manage relationships between different objects (in your case this is producers and products).

Comment: Hello, I have read up on Normalization - 1NF, 2NF and 3NF. I would like to ask in this case, how would I approach this if I want it in 3NF. I have separate tables for producers and for products, but how would I go about making the third table to join what products each producer has? I want to avoid duplicates for each product.

Comment: Would I have to go about it for example by making a table called BobsProducts and having Producer_ID and Product_ID in it and then making a new table for JohnsProducts and doing the same?

Comment: @KaneVoltaire No, the whole point of your third table is it defines the relationship between every producer and their products. You would have a `producers_products` table with `producer_id` and `product_id`. In that table you store all of Bob's products with his producer ID and whatever product IDs he has. You also store all of John's products, with his producer ID and product IDs that he has.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a standard MySQL database a cell can only hold data in a predetermined data type. This type is defined when creating the table.

It is possible to store a JSON array in there but I don't recommend it, rather, I'd look into structuring your database in a different way.

Perhaps have one table that stores the producer data and one that stores all the associated products.